# software-properties-gtk (software and updates) window not showing for any apparent reason

Tags: update-manager, python3

Whenever I click the icon to launch `software and updates`, the program starts and then stops. I even try to launch it from the command line and the same thing happens.

```python
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gdk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
```

This behaviour is strange because the command exits without any errors (`echo $?`). What else could be causing it to fail like this?

[image]
[image]

Strangely enough, if I launch it as root (`gksu software-properties-gtk`), it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the version of python I had installed as a user did not include the the gtk libraries required for this program to run.

When I ran it as root, it was using the system's python installation, which had all those libraries already built in, so naturally it worked then.

This problem has been fixed in later versions of `software-properties-gtk` because the shebang line at the top of the program now says:

`#!/usr/bin/python3` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

*The later causes it to use the users's own version of python3, while the former (and now the defacto) is using the system installed version of python3*